# Couple questions about android EditText and ListView and databases

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out which one is the best to use EditText or ListView to store and retrieve data from a database. The data has to be written to and taken from separate fields in the activity and stored in a database. Also the data has to be read from the database and place back into the separate fields.I'm starting the UI and wondering which is better.

Comment: Ok i c...I want to input data into edit text fields and take that data and store it in a database. Also i want to take that data from the database and place them into the same fields where they can be edited if needed and stored back in the data base. i hope thats better.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more in your question? I did it using Listview and it was simple but I can't help you on the EditText view approach. If you will edit dynamically then update you should go with EditText view.

Thanks
V.k

Comment: Ok i c...I want to input data into edit text fields and take that data and store it in a database. Also i want to take that data from the database and place them into the same fields where they can be edited if needed and stored back in the data base. i hope thats better

Comment: Yeah ...u should go with list view in which you will populate your edit textview using custom adapter.In a list view,you can bind any view using custom adapter.If you can make adapter your own then fine otherwise tell me,i can suggest you an example which can help you more.

Comment: Yes..thanks..could you suggest an example to help me more. I have put everything in an EditView. Do u know if using the listview will involve me having to change them all. Not to familiar on how listview works. thanks again

Comment: I put an example for help on this link:http://rorraja.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-use-listview-using-custom.html Please see this for much help if u getting any problem in this tell me..This example is working for me and i put in this only hint how you can do??  Try to understand if you can do your own then fine else i will help you more in this..You need to change textview with the edittextview for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not much clear.You cant store these data in edit text or listview,you can just call database to show those data in edittext or in listview.So  make the question clear.